# 2012 R2 VDI Setup - No Virtual Templates

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, rds, vdi

I've installed Win 2012 R2 Standard and setting up the RDS role for VDI. I plan to have a pool of virtual desktops. I have done this before and have had no problems so I am very familiar with the entire process but i believe i may be missing something minor this time around.

When i get to the step to select the Virtual Desktop Template, nothing shows up in the list. I have already installed and sys prepped a Windows 8 Enterprise VM as well as a Win 7 Enterprise VM. Neither of them shows in the template list.

Google searches lead to step by step instructions or guidelines which does not help. Some have also recommended re-doing everything which i have also tried (remove/reinstall all RDS roles and features + hyperv)

[image]

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that you cannot run RDS Virtualization Host role on an domain controller. I understand the reason and would never do this in a production environment, this was a lab setup.

I am answering this for anyone in future. I think there should be some kind of alert or notation somewhere minimum, but preferably it should not allow you to select the checkbox during role selection if it's on a domain controller.

Comment: Seriously? That is why I couldn't get it to show up. Thanks @KhalidRahaman!  Also I agree there was no warning or mention that I could not do this, and there should have been. Bad Microsoft, bad!

Comment: Thanks Khalid, I was using a similar setup and was wondering why my template machine wasn't showing. My setup was for a test domain to keep it self contained on one host, obviously i'll have to rethink. Thanks for posting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have two Windows 2012 R2 servers running hyper-v with one also running RDS. Both servers are DC's. I have no problem with RDS with vdi. I have two collections. One for Win 7 the other Win 8. I have also setup a separate server also with Windows 2012 R2 for RDWEB to publish applications.

Did you receive any errors when sysprepping the machine? I initially received errors and reverted to using the command line rather than GUI.

I have seen several sites saying RDS cannot run on a DC but this is not true. I have it running in a DC server with no problems.

One thing I did do before running sysprep was run windows updates so the template is up to date.

I did find that I had to elevate the server permissions in AD in order for the server to create the machines from the template. I had to restart the server for this to take effect too.